# The URL timed out. Make sure it is responding in a timely fashion to requests from Google.Dismiss

Tags: google-pagespeed

I am checking website link in https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

One url link is working and the other one (from the same site) is not. This message is coming up:

```
The URL timed out. Make sure it is responding in a timely fashion to requests from Google.Dismiss
```

My website is http://five.vn.

Can someone help to understand why it is not working or what may I do to test it?

Thanks

Comment: Does it say which link is not working?

Comment: FWIW I get this error too and there's no reason for it. My URLs work fine in the [amp testing tool](https://search.google.com/test/amp) which links me to the SD testing tool, which gives me this error. It's not the speed of my site, but something else blocking it. I haven't figured out the real problem, but for others getting this error, know that there's other reasons!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be responding at the moment, but is very slow. Time to first byte is almost a second which indicates that it takes a lot of time for the server to generate the page. You should consider using some kind of cache or a more powerful server.

Comment: Exactly what is the timeout time for the Google Bot?

Comment: If it's fast enough for the [amp testing tool](https://search.google.com/test/amp) but not the SD testing tool, that's a real mystery. I think the SD testing tool has some special problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is the current response that I get from Structured Data Testing Page:

This tool is being shut down
The Structured Data Testing Tool is being deprecated. For validating structured data for Google Search, Google now recommends using the Rich Results Test for more accurate and actionable feedback. For more information on this deprecation, read our blog post.

https://search.google.com/test/rich-results